# Меньше слов больше дела. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Перед ***больше*** нужно поставить тире или запятую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) ***Меньше слов, больше дела.*** (2) ***Меньше слов — больше дела.***

Это БСП (бессоюзное предложение), но отношения между частями разные. В первом случае предложения **равноправные,** а во втором — **зависимые, взаимообусловленные** (когда/если меньше слов, то больше дела).

Тире делит предложение **на две части,** сопоставляя или противопоставляя их.

Варианты применяются по ситуации.

1) *Меньше слов, больше дела — таков мой принцип.*

2) *Я не люблю рассказывать о своих планах: меньше слов — больше дела.*

Answer (score 2):

Ответ зависит от того смысла, какой Вы хотите заложить в свою фразу. Если Вы подразумеваете "Меньше слов И больше дела", имеет смысл поставить запятую. Если же Вы хотите сказать "Где меньше слов, там больше дела" или "Когда меньше слов, тогда больше дела", тире мне кажется более уместным.

Comment: Но общепринято только первое значение.

Answer (score 1):

Тире не требуется, но его можно поставить – для усиления противопоставления.